# perl cgi - change location for temporary uploaded files

Tags: perl, upload, cgi, temp

Having moved an existing script to a new server, a function is not working anymore :

```
$CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $TempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $temp_dir;
```

I discovered that : "Changes in temporary file handling (v4.05+) : CGI.pm had its temporary file handling significantly refactored, this logic is now all deferred to File::Temp [...]" that you can fully read here : [Link to CGI doc](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.22/lib/CGI.html)

Consequently I search in the documentation of File::Temp (and many forums) but found nothing on how to change the path for temporary files.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

P. S. For the context it looks like this

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
[...]
$CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $TempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $temp_dir;
[...]
my $cg = new CGI;
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/source/LEEJO/CGI-4.36/lib/CGI.pm#L1025 so it should be `$ENV{TEMP}` for windows and `$ENV{TMPDIR}` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot, Сухой27, for your comment, the solution is very simple (once you know it) I just replaced the code above with :

```
$ENV{TMPDIR}=$temp_dir;
```